# Installed 32-bit Windows instead of 64-bit on my MacBook Air

Tags: bootcamp, usb, driver

Installed 32-bit Windows instead of 64-bit on my MacBook Air 2011. The Boot camp drivers are for 64-bit Windows 8 so they can't be installed. It doesn't see any USB drive including my external DVD drive.

Are there are any work arounds other than reinstalling 64-bit windows?

Comment: Grammar check isn't a bad idea. *We have the technology!*

Comment: Are you Windows 7 or 8? If Windows 7, use Bootcamp 4. If Windows 8, read this post: http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/1g9n9g/how_to_install_windows_8_in_bootcamp_on_an_older/ starting from the 21st bullet point

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall....